# google.script.run not working in jQuery when modal dialog 'submitted'

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

Good afternoon all;

I am working on a Google web app that will gather user input through buttons and jQuery modal dialogs, push the captured data to Google Sheets as the backend database (just trialing the app before paying to work with Google Cloud SQL), and then grab that information back and populate it in HTML fields (I've only been coding for less than a week so hope this makes sense).

I cannot get the google.script.run function to work *unless* it comes before the variables but then of course it does not push the information that I want. Can someone let me know what is going wrong here? And, please excuse anything I'm doing weird and any formatting - only been at this less than a week!

**HTML** (**EDIT: INPUT MY WHOLE HTML**)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
      <?!= include("Dashboard-css");  ?>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color:#fffafa;">

<!-- CREATE USER DETAILS DIALOG BOX -->
  <div id="dialog-form">
    <p><center> CREATE OR UPDATE PROFILE </center></p>
      <form>
        <fieldset>

          <input type="text" id="htmlCompanyName" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <label for="htmlCompanyName">Company Name</label>

          <input type="text" name="formUserName" id="htmlUserName" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <label for="formUserName">First Name & Last Name</label>

          <input type="text" name="formUserAddress" id="htmlUserAddress" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <label for="formUserAddress">Address</label>

          <input type="text" name="formUserEmail" id="htmlUserEmail" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <label for="formUserEmail">Email</label>

          <input type="text" name="formUserPhone" id="htmlUserPhone" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <label for="formUserPhone">Phone Number</label>

<!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
          <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
  </div>

<!-- Formatting container for the actual HTML body -->  
  <div class="container">
      <h5 style="font-family:sans-serif"><center>Arts & Venue Project Tracker</center></h5>

<!-- CREATE BUTTON -->    
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col">
            <p class="z-depth-1">
              <button id="setUserDetails" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" style="font-size:75%";>Create or Update Profile</button>
            </p>
          </div>    
        </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW FOR BUTTON -->

        <div style ="display: table;" id="masterUserTable">
          <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;font-size:75%" id="companyName">Company:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;font-size:75%" id="companyNameEntry"></div>
          </div>
          <div style="display: table-row;">      
            <div style="display: table-cel;font-size:75%" id="userName">Name:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;font-size:75%" id="userNameEntry"></div>        
          </div>
          <div style="display: table-row;">      
            <div style="display: table-cell;font-size:75%" id="userAddress">Address:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;font-size:75%" id="userAddressEntry"></div>
          </div>
          <div style="display: table-row;">      
            <div style="display: table-cell;font-size:75%" id="userEmail">Email:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;font-size:75%" id="userEmailEntry"></div>        
          </div>
          <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;font-size:75%" id="userPhone">Phone:<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;font-size:75%" id="userPhoneEntry"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <?!= include("Dashboard-js");  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery** (look at function addUpdateUser())

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready( function() {

    var dialog, form,
    wWidth = $(window).width(),
    dWidth = (wWidth*0.5),
    wHeight = $(window).height(),
    dHeight = (wHeight*0.95),   
    jCompanyName = $( "#htmlCompanyName" ),
    jUserName = $( "#htmlUserName" ),
    jUserAddress = $( "#htmlUserAddress" ),
    jUserEmail = $( "#htmlUserEmail" ),
    jUserPhone = $( "#htmlUserPhone" );

//What happens when 'Confirm' in the modal dialog is clicked
      function addUpdateUser() { 

        var asCompanyNameEntry = $( "#companyNameEntry" ).html(jCompanyName.val()),
        asUserNameEntry = $( "#userNameEntry" ).html(jUserName.val()),
        asUserAddressEntry = $( "#userAddressEntry" ).html(jUserAddress.val()),
        asUserEmailEntry = $( "#userEmailEntry" ).html(jUserEmail.val()),
        asUserPhoneEntry = $( "#userPhoneEntry" ).html(jUserPhone.val());

        google.script.run.userSetDetails(asUserNameEntry); //Currently, this is not executing and is preventing the next line from executing, but it runs if put before the variables

        dialog.dialog( "close" );
    }

//Open the Dialog Box
      dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: dHeight,
        width: dWidth,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          "Confirm": addUpdateUser,
          Cancel: function() {
            dialog.dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
          close: function() {
            form[ 0 ].reset();
          }
      });

      form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addUpdateUser();
      });

//Put the captured details into the HTML file and recapture it in the dialog box when button is reclicked
  $( "#setUserDetails" ).on("click",function(){  

       var companyNameEnteredValue = $( "#companyNameEntry" ).html(),
       userNameEnteredValue =  $( "#userNameEntry" ).html(),
       userAddressEnteredValue =  $( "#userAddressEntry" ).html(),
       userEmailEnteredValue =  $( "#userEmailEntry" ).html(),
       userPhoneEnteredValue =  $( "#userPhoneEntry" ).html();

       $( "#htmlCompanyName" ).val(companyNameEnteredValue);
       $( "#htmlUserName" ).val(userNameEnteredValue);
       $( "#htmlUserAddress" ).val(userAddressEnteredValue);
       $( "#htmlUserEmail" ).val(userEmailEnteredValue);
       $( "#htmlUserPhone" ).val(userPhoneEnteredValue);

       dialog.dialog("open"); 

      });
});
</script>
```

**Google Apps Script**

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Dashboard").evaluate();  
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function userSetDetails(asUserNameEntry){
  var masterFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(asUserNameEntry + " Revenue and Expense Tracking - PIVOT Web App"); 
  var masterFolderId = masterFolder.getId();      
  var userMainDashboard = {

    "title": asUserNameEntry + " Main Dashboard",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
    "parents": [
        {
          "id": masterFolderId 
        }
      ] 
    };

Drive.Files.insert(userMainDashboard);
}
```

**Resolution**

d'oh, it was a relatively simple error to catch once I tried to rebuild the code through the minimal reproducible example. When trying to call 'asUserNameEntry' in google.script.run, I needed to call its string value, so I just had to add .text() to the end so that it was google.script.run(asUserNameEntry.text()) and then the script grabbed the entered text value! Thank you all for your support though - great to see such quick and kind responses from the community!

Comment: provide error logs in the "browser"'s console

Comment: JQuery declaration should be in the head.  But there is no opening`<html>` or `<head></head>`

Comment: Do you really want  the `addUpdateUser()` declaration within the document ready function?

Comment: @TheMaster is this what you mean?
[..] Failed due to illegal value in property: constructor
at le (3488998431-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:57)
at he (3488998431-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:57)
at 3488998431-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:21
at Object.userSetDetails (3488998431-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:56)
at HTMLDivElement.addUpdateUser (userCodeAppPanel:24)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.min.js:11)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @Cooper When I move the addUpdateUser() declaration outside of the document ready function, the modal dialog form bugs out and shows up at the top of the page instead of as a popup.

Comment: @Cooper fixed my post to include my entire HTML. Apologies for omitting sections.

Comment: yes. [edit] the errors into your question. It seems some of the value is illegal. See [mcve]. The code can be minimal, but should also be loadable in apps script.

Comment: Did you check 1. either you can run `function userSetDetails()` manualy from the editor hardcoding the value of `asUserNameEntry`? 2. console.log `asUserNameEntry` within `function addUpdateUser()` before `google.scritp.run`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d'oh, it was a relatively simple error to catch once I tried to rebuild the code through the minimal reproducible example. When trying to call 'asUserNameEntry' in google.script.run, I needed to call its string value, so I just had to add .text() to the end so that it was google.script.run(asUserNameEntry.text()) and then the script grabbed the entered text value! Thank you all for your support though - great to see such quick and kind responses from the community!